# how to convert a joomla 2.5 plugin to 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a plugin for joomla 2.5 
I want install it in joomla 3 but after installing I see this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JController::getInstance() in /home/xxx/public_html/administrator/components/xxx/xxx.php on line 21

Line of error:

```
// Require specific controller if requested
if($controller = JRequest::getCmd('controller'))
{
    $path = JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controllers'.DS.$controller.'.php';

    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        require_once $path;
    }
    else
    {
        $controller = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JController::getInstance()` has been removed. Use `JControllerLegacy::getInstance()` instead.